# XSLT: strip tags, preserve whitespace

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Using XSLT, I'm trying to strip out all tags within a particular node, while preserving the whitespace between those tags.

I'm given XML like this:

```
<text>
<s id="s2"> The patient is a <p id="p22">56-year-old</p> <p id="p28">Caucasian</p> <p id="p30">male</p></s></text>
```

I'd like to strip out all of the <s> and <p> tags so that I just have the English sentence within the <text> node.

I've tried the following template, which does successfully remove all of the tags, but it also removes the spaces between the <p> tags if there are no other characters there. For example, I would end up with: " The patient is a 56-year-oldCaucasianmale"

```
<xsl:template name="strip-tags">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text content with whitespace preserved but tags removed is precisely the definition of "string value" for an element node.  So you could simply use

```
<xsl:value-of select="$text" />
```

(assuming `$text` contains the `<text>` element node).  This also assumes that you *don't* have

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

in your stylesheet, as that would strip the whitespace-only text nodes between the various pairs of `</p> <p>` tags.

Comment: Ah, good to know! But even doing this, whitespace between the p tags is removed. If I replace the spaces in the XML with non-space characters, those characters are preserved.

Comment: @embden do you have an `<xsl:strip-space>` in your stylesheet?

Comment: You may be using the Microsoft XML parser which notoriously strips whitespace by default. Once it's gone, there's nothing XSLT can do to save it.

Comment: @MichaelKay: It wasn't Microsoft's, but Altova's MapForce application. I just discovered this: data "is stripped of boundary-whitespace-only text nodes" http://manual.altova.com/mapforce/mapforce-basic/index.html?xslt1engineimplementation.htm

Thanks, guys

Comment: Altova uses the Microsoft XML parser underneath.